# How to do a RedirectResponse with a destination query parameter?

Tags: 8, redirection

This works:

```
$redirectURL = '/cart/add/p2';
return new RedirectResponse(base_path().$redirectURL);
```

The problem is, I want this:

```
$redirectURL = '/cart/add/p2?destination=somewhere';
```

The moment I added destination=somewhere, I get this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The internal path component 'http://localhost/XXXX/public_html/XXXX/XXXX' is invalid. Its path component must have a leading slash, e.g. internal:/foo. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromInternalUri() (line 404 of C:\ampps\www\XXXX\public_html\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Url.php).
```

However, if I do this:

```
$redirectURL = '/cart/add/p2?SOMETHING_ELSE=somewhere';
```

Then it works. In other words, it specifically breaks if I add "destination=somewhere".

Why would it be breaking on this and how do I get around it? I.e. How do I redirect to a URL with destination=somewhere in the query string.

FYI: If I can get this to work, I can use "Cart Links" to add stuff to a cart and redirect the user at the same time, making my live a lot easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Better use a route, so that the path processing in Drupal can do its job. 
If `custom.cart_add` is the route to `/cart/add/{page}`, this returns a redirect response with a destination query parameter from a controller:

```
  return $this->redirect(
    'custom.cart_add',
    ['page' => 'p2'],
    [
      'query' => ['destination' => 'somewhere'],
      'absolute' => TRUE,
    ]
  );
```

Comment: This only works in the context of a controller, which isnt always the case (e.g. I am handling `onKernelRequest`)

Comment: @Jeff, the question was about returning a response from a controller. In an event subscriber you can create a new RedirectResponse like in the other answers, but don't send the response, set it in the event: `$event->setResponse()`

Answer (score 7):

Try this code.

```
$path = Drupal\Core\URL::fromUserInput('/cart/add/p2', array('query' => array('SOMETHING_ELSE' => 'somewhere')))->toString();
$response = new RedirectResponse($path);
$response->send();
```

Comment: Same problem. That toString just turns my string into one that has "destination=bla", and the moment you have "destination=bla" in the "new RedirectResponse" bit, it breaks.

Comment: @coderama Try updated code and let me know if it is not working with the error message.

Comment: Please note case sensitivity on the class name. It should be "Drupal\Core\Url::"

Answer (score 5):

This full example might help:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;

$target = 65; // a parameter you want to add
$url = Url::fromUri('internal:/node/add/page'); // choose a path
$link_options = array(
  'attributes' => array(
     'class' => array(
        'btn',
     ),
   ),
   'query' => array(
     'target' => $target
   )
);
$url->setOptions($link_options);
$destination = $url->toString();

$response = new RedirectResponse($destination);
$response->send();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$redirectURL = '/cart/add/p2';
return new RedirectResponse(base_path().$redirectURL);
```

The code above produces double slash before the *cart* item, because `base_path()` always adds a slash at the end of the returned path. You need to remove the slash from `$redirectURL` variable to get it work correctly.