# Return from Controller is expected to be array, how to return an array that redirects?

Tags: 8

I have a "redirect" query parameter in my URL.
I get this parameter and after doing some things I want to redirect.

But the `content()` method is expected to return an `array`, so returning Symfony's `RedirectResponse` is giving me a warning in PHPStorm.

What is the correct way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Controllers that extend ControllerBase can return a render array or a Symfony Response object. Do you have a return type specified on the class method or something? See: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/255216/57

Comment: Yes, probably the example `content()` you used contains the annotation `@return array`. Remove this to get rid of the warning.